# Web server - IOs Developer Enterprise Program

Tags: ios, server

we're newbies in the development for IOs. We need to build an app for use in an Iphone. The app is private. Based in the official docs, we decided get the certificate for "IOs Developer Enterprise Program".

According the docs (please correct if i'm wrong), our apps need this to run:

1 Certificate for the enterprise (provided by apple when the contract is signed)
1 Certificate for distribution
1 Profile for distribution

Install the certificates in a server (third party, or ours own)

In a lot of youtube videos the developers build the certificates from a equipment with OSX.

Now my question. Once we have all the certificates, Can We install those  into any private server independently of the plataform?. For example in a linux with Apache, Ngix or a Windows Server with IIS, or the only works if the server is  a Mac with Mac OS X ...?

That's all. Sorry for my english. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could deploy a App with any Webserver. You will get an Path for the Filename, and if you load this into your Safari from your device, you are able to install the App.

Check out more here:
https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/gettingstarted/

And this here for Deployment Strategies:

http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/it/deployment.html